# Antlr4 ignores tokens

Tags: token, grammar, antlr4, lexer

In ANTLR 4 I try to parse a text file, but some of my defined tokens are constantly ignored in favor of others. I produced a small example to show what I mean:

File to parse:

```
hello world
hello world
```

Grammar:

```
grammar TestLexer;

file : line line;
line : 'hello' ' ' 'world' '\n';

LINE : ~[\n]+? '\n';
```

The ANTLR book explains that 'hello' would become an implicit token, which is placed before the LINE token, and that token order matters. So I'd expect that the parser would NOT match the LINE token, but it does, as the resulting tree shows:

[image: Unexpected Result]

How can I fix this, so that I get the actual implicit tokens?

Btw. I also tried to write explicit tokens before LINE, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it myself:

It seems that ANTLR chooses *longest tokens first*.
So since LINE would always match a whole line it is always preferred.

To still include some "joker" token into a grammar it should be a single symbol.
In my case

```
grammar TestLexer;

file : line line;
line : 'hello' ' ' 'world' '\n';

LINE : ~[\n];
```

would work.

Comment: It chooses the longest token and if there is more than 1 candidate, it chooses the first (topmost) of them.

Comment: If you want to do anything useful with LINE in your parser or post processing it should be a parser rule anyway. In most cases it's only ok to match a large amount of text for a single token for comments etc.

Comment: I wanted to use it more for an incomplete grammar, where I have a Token that matches everything that is not yet covered. So, in the end I don't expect anything to be matched by that token anymore.